# SQL Server : stored procedure transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Hello I got some stored procedures to create products and other stuff on my site. Now I have to run some of them in a transaction. Is that possible or do I have to make a stored procedure only for the transaction?

Can I say something like

```
BEGIN TRAN
"1. stored procedure"
"2. stored procedure"
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To add to the other answers above, you may want to add some error handling:

```
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY

   EXEC P1

   EXEC P2

   COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRAN

END CATCH
```

---

Update with C# code (I personally find it a lot easier to keep trans code out of the sprocs and in the data layer - makes composing stored procedures easier at a later stage):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))

    trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

    try
   {
       ...call P1 using transaction
       ...call P2 using transaction

       trans.Commit();
   }
   catch
   {
       trans.RollBack();
       throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: try catch isent that Gregs answer just an easier way. ? 
he checks every return value and then stop. if one dident return 0.
thaks for the answer!.

Comment: now i got it to work with the try catch but if i make it fail can i send a rows effected number or something like that to see when it fails.

Comment: You can send whatever you need from the catch - slightly different from Gregs answer - say you needed to add a third proc, the if...else answer would rapidly get quite complex.  also, if it fails, no rows will be affected - you're rolling it back..?

Comment: yes if and else will be complex that im aware of. 
before i got my try catch in the c# code so if the query failed it showed an error but now i got the error handling in the sql so i need something to sendt back as result of the query.

Comment: You could keep the try...catch in your C# code and use a SqlTransaction to manage your transaction from the calling code.  I personally find it a lot easier to keep trans code out of the sprocs and in the data layer.  Makes composing stored procedures easier at a later stage.

Comment: Try...Catch is also a great way to do this (assuming sql 2005 or newer). I'd often use a try...catch in SQL if I wanted to process something else after it failed. E.g. if your stored proc failed then you can call rollback tran, insert log entry, then return to c# (with or without an error). Perfectly good to do this from c# as well.

Comment: thanks for all the answers. now I have it set op and it works but if i need a id from the first procedure to be set in the next procedure how can i make that happen ? :)

Comment: Given the C# code above, return this from the first procedure and pass it as a parameter to the second?

Comment: I made so i can give the transaction 2-infiniti procedures so the transaction can take care of it by itself. but then sometime I need a id returned from the first procedure so I can set the id in the next or following procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a stored procedure can be run inside a transaction. Please find below a sample query.

```
create table temp1
(
    id int,
    name varchar(20)
)

create table temp2
(
    id int,
    name varchar(20)
)
go

create proc p1 as
insert temp1 values (1, 'test1')


create proc p2 as 
insert temp2 values (1, 'test2')
go  

begin tran tx
exec p1
exec p2
commit
```

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server (not sure about other RDBMS), You can call multiple stored procedures inside a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRAN
EXEC StoredProc1
EXEC StoredProc2
COMMIT TRAN
```

You may want to add a return code to the stored proc to check if you should run stored proc 2 if stored proc 1 failed

EDIT:
To check a return code you can do something like the following. This will run the first stored proc. If it returns 0 then it runs the 2nd. If the 2nd returns 0 then it commits the transaction. If either returns non-0 then it will rollback the transaction

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT
BEGIN TRAN
  EXEC @ReturnValue = StoredProc1
  IF @ReturnValue = 0
  BEGIN
    EXEC @ReturnValue = StoredProc2
    IF @ReturnValue = 0
    BEGIN
      COMMIT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK
    END
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
  END
```

Comment: Should have added, if stored proc 2 fails then it will be able to rollback stored proc 1

Comment: so if i got a return code on storedproc1 how do i check the value. sorry im not good at sql. but thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
Begin TRAN
BEGIN TRY
  -- your Action
  Commit TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  END 
END CATCH
```