# Concurrency, Locking in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to Save/Update data in 15 tables. I have to ensure at the time of updation the concurrency and locking should be maintained, so that no dirty read happens. I am updating data using storeed procedure. What I can do in oredr to implement locking and concurrency?

Comment: I think the first step would be to do a google search on it and read about it. Then when you have specific questions about your implementation of it, you should come back to Stack Overflow and ask those specific questions.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers are assuming that you are already using a transaction. I won't omit this, since you might be missing it.

**You should use a transaction** to ensure that records in all 15 tables or none are inserted/updated. The transaction ensures you atomicity in your operation. If something fails during the stored procedure and you don't use a transaction, some of the save/update operations will be made, and some not (the ones from the query that has produced the error).

If you use [BEGIN TRAN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188929.aspx), and COMMIT for successful operations or ROLLBACK in case of failure, you will get all done or nothing. You should check for errors after each query execution, and call ROLLBACK TRANSACTION if there is one, or call COMMIT at the end of the stored procedure.

There is a good sample in [the accepted answer of this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032890/sql-server-stored-procedure-transaction) on how to handle transaction inside a stored procedure.

Once you have the transaction, the second part is **how to avoid dirty reads**. You can set the isolation level of your database to READ COMMITED, this will prevent, by default, dirty reads on your data. But the user can still chose to do dirty reads by specifying **[WITH (NOLOCK) or READUNCOMMITED](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/)** in his query. You cannot prevent that.

Besides, there are the snapshot isolation levels (Snapshot and Read Commited Snapshot) that could prevent locking (which is not always good), avoiding dirty reads at the same time.

There is a lot of literature on this topic over the internet. If you are interested in snapshot isolation levels, I suggest you to read this **[great article from Kendra Little at Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)**.

Comment: Downvoted, because You are ALWAYS using a transaction. It is not possible to execute a statement in SQL Server (or any database) that is NOT in a transaction.  The `Begin Transaction` statement only allows you to place MULTIPLE statements in the same transaction.

Comment: Dear @CharlesBretana, Of course, and I am telling that he should wrap all his 15 queries inside the stored procedure within a transaction. He is indeed running multiple statements, since he is updating 15 tables inside a stored procedure.

Comment: @Jamie,  yes, I see that now, you are right, my apologies, I will remove my downvote..

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent that dirty read does not happen. Is the **reader** that does the dirty reads, not you (the writer). All you can do is ensure that your write is *atomic*, and that is accomplished by wrapping all writes in a single transaction. This way readers that do not issue dirty reads will see either all your updates, either none (atomic).

If a reader chooses to issue dirty reads **there's nothing you can do about it**.

Note that changing *your* isolation level has no effect whatsoever on the reader's isolation level.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I am sorry to say that this is not true if you set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation level in your database. Once you set it on, all queries will start using row-versioned data, affecting all readers.

Comment: @Jaime: a simple test can show the opposite. There is a reason  is called `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` not `EVERY_READ_SNAPSHOT`...

Comment: Also, enabling READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT changes readers. Remus says that it is necessary to change readers, and that's true.

Comment: @RemusRusanu You are right. I misunderstood you. My apologies

Comment: I meant that READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT changes how data is read to the default READ_COMMITED isolation level.It removes locking from that isolation level and uses rows versioning, changing the way data is read and likely the results returned

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to ensure that the [sql server isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) is set appropriately.  To eliminate dirty reads, it needs to be at *Read Committed* or higher, (Not at *Read Uncommitted*). *Read Committed* is the default setting out of the box.

It might be worth while, however, to review the link above and see what benefits, (and consequences) the higher settings provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE. by using the following statement

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

Before you BEGIN TRANSACTION but **Warning** it can slow down other user who will be try to see on update or insert data into your tables, Your can also make use of the SNAP_SHOT Isolation Level which shows you only the last Commited/Saved data but it makes extensive use of Temp DB which can also effect the performance.