# Data Transaction Issues in Multi-User Application - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, transactions

We are developing a data-critical application which will be accessed by multiple users at the same time.
We are using Microsoft sql server as the database. The isolation level is `read committed`. We carried out
`transaction control` explicitly to the stored procedures which inserts or updates the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_Procedure Template]
@Param1      INT,   
@Param2      INT,   
@DestYear    INT,   
@destSeason  INT    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    -- select statements 
    -- insert statements /update statements


    IF @@ERROR = 0
        BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN;
    END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END CATCH

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
GO
```

But when multiple users carried out `Insertion/Updation`  at the same time, issues occurs in
the application (though very often). for eg:  `parent table` records not being updated into `child table` and some times
the records inserted the `child table` not belongs to the `parent table`.

My questions:

1. Do we need to implement any Table hints (i.e.TabLock, Row-lock) on the data-critical tables?
   (we are currently using `NOLOCK` hint in Read-only /reporting tables)
2. Do we need to implement `explicit transaction control` on the stored procedures which reads data from the database?
3. In some of the stored procedures we implemented `explicit transaction control` only in the blocks which insert/update
   the original/base tables (to make the transactions short). i.e we excluded temp table/table variable population, 
   variable assign block etc. Is it a problem?

Comment: It it always a single call to a sproc when there is an action in your application, or are multiple sprocs called for a single action?

Comment: mostly multiple sprocs are called for each record change. In some module we used table types to pull the data together from the application and call the sp's only once

Comment: Then you have the issue that when one sproc fails, there may be data from previous calls already committed and data in an unexpected state.

Comment: I would recommend holding your transaction code in your application and not in your sproc.  Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032890/sql-server-stored-procedure-transaction/12033351#12033351

Comment: @thanks. let me look into it. but i think failing in a procedure call would not leads to data inconsistency, since each procedure call inserts/update both child and parent table

Comment: 'data-critical', but in a single action, one call can succeed and one fail (when expected to succeed) and that's ok?  First call and data there won't be rolled back.

Comment: ok i understand. But could you give any suggestion regarding the sproc structure?. does it need any further improvement?

Comment: Your question is in general too broad.  Deadlocks are hard to track down and there can be multiple reasons for them.  A simple template structure will not be enough on it's own.  Your orphaned records are a result of multiple individual transactions rather than a single atomic transaction to save parent and child.